# Cannot move cursor in textbox using mouse in windows child form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows

I am developing an application where I have a parent (main) from. Inside parent (main) form, I open a child form. The textbox in child form, I cannot move cursor using mouse. I want to move cursor any where I want in textbox using mouse.

In main form even I used panel and child forms are opened in Panel

Comment: Is your textbox empty? (Do you want to move the (text) cursor to places where there are no characters?)

Comment: No I have a text written in textbox

Comment: There is a property called TopMost in form class. Use that property if you are intending to show your child form on top of the parent with full focus.

Comment: It did this but the issue remains same

Comment: I don't know why this was upvoted three times, but you need to show some relevant code if you want anyone to be able to properly answer this.

Comment: actually I didn't do any code for this, what I want is when I open child window and in text area if any where I just point the mouse , I should be able to do, but right now it always goes to the first place and I have to manually keep shift it place using arraow keys in key board

Comment: If you can clearify your question more, that would be appropriate. Try uploading some related pictures or codes  of your program. There might be several possible answers for your question, so be narrow and specific.

Comment: TopMost is a bad idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way out.
I removed the Panel form parent form and it solved my problem.

Comment: This answer bears no relation to the question that was asked.

Comment: Could you please tell me how